# Java Trie Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, trie

I am creating a Trie class in Java, and am wondering what else can be done to make it even better. I am hoping to add concurrency to speed querying up.

```
public class Trie {
    private HashMap<Character, HashMap> root;
    private final Character END_CHARACTER = '$';

    public Trie() {
        initializeRoot();
    }

    public Trie(String s) {
        initializeRoot();
        add(s);
    }

    public Trie(Collection<String> collection) {
        initializeRoot();
        for (String s : collection) {
            add(s);
        }
    }

    private void initializeRoot() {
        root = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (!node.containsKey(character)) {
                node.put(character, new HashMap<Character, HashMap>());
            }
            node = node.get(character);
        }
        node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public boolean contains(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (node.containsKey(character)) {
                node = node.get(character);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return node.containsKey(END_CHARACTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initializing `private HashMap<Character, HashMap> root;` at declaration will simplify your code

```
public class Trie {
    private HashMap<Character, HashMap> root = new HashMap<>();
    private final Character END_CHARACTER = '$';

    public Trie() {}

    public Trie(String s) {
        add(s);
    }

    public Trie(Collection<String> collection) {
        for (String s : collection) {
            add(s);
        }
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (!node.containsKey(character)) {
                node.put(character, new HashMap<Character, HashMap>());
            }
            node = node.get(character);
        }
        node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public boolean contains(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (node.containsKey(character)) {
                node = node.get(character);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return node.containsKey(END_CHARACTER);
    }
}
```

From [whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/2655508)

> Simply put, this is wrong because it unnecessarily opens up possibilities to MANY bugs. When the @Override is invoked, the state of the object may be inconsistent and/or incomplete.

This having in mind we will refactor the class, to add a private `internalAdd()` method which we call from the constructor and the `public add()` methods

```
public class Trie {
    private HashMap<Character, HashMap> root = new HashMap<>();
    private final Character END_CHARACTER = '$';

    public Trie() {}

    public Trie(String s) {
        internalAdd(s);
    }

    public Trie(Collection<String> collection) {
        for (String s : collection) {
            internalAdd(s);
        }
    }

    public void add(String s) {
        internalAdd(s);
    }

    private void internalAdd(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (!node.containsKey(character)) {
                node.put(character, new HashMap<Character, HashMap>());
            }
            node = node.get(character);
        }
        node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
    }

    public boolean contains(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (node.containsKey(character)) {
                node = node.get(character);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return node.containsKey(END_CHARACTER);
    }
}
```

but we can do better.. let us take a look at `internalAdd()`

> ```
> private void internalAdd(String s) {
>     HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
>     for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
>         Character character = s.charAt(i);
>         if (!node.containsKey(character)) {
>             node.put(character, new HashMap<Character, HashMap>());
>         }
>         node = node.get(character);
>     }
>     node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
> }
> ```

If `node.isEmpty()` we won't need to check `if (!node.containsKey(character))` anymore.
Also if `(!node.containsKey(character))` evaluates one time to `true`, we won't need to check this anymore. Let us add a new method:

```
private void internalAdd(String s, HashMap<Character, HashMap> node) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character character = s.charAt(i);
        node.put(character, new HashMap<>());
        node = node.get(character);
    }
}
```

and call it

```
private void internalAdd(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        Character character = s.charAt(i);
        if (node.isEmpty() || !node.containsKey(character)) {
            internalAdd(s.substring(i), node);
            break;
        }
        node = node.get(character);
    }
    node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
}
```

But wait, we can do even better, as `node.isEmpty()` should also be used in the `contains()` method

```
public boolean contains(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if(node.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        Character character = s.charAt(i);
        if (node.containsKey(character)) {
            node = node.get(character);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return node.containsKey(END_CHARACTER);
}
```

Finished ? No, we still can do better. As the passed String parameters won't be changed, let us make them `final` the same is true for the `root` field. Also as [janos](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos) has answered

> use interface types instead of the implementation

Putting altogether

```
public class Trie {

    private final Map<Character, HashMap> root = new HashMap<>();
    private final Character END_CHARACTER = '$';

    public Trie() {
    }

    public Trie(final String s) {
        internalAdd(s);
    }

    public Trie(final Collection<String> collection) {
        for (String s : collection) {
            internalAdd(s);
        }
    }

    public void add(final String s) {
        internalAdd(s);
    }

    private void internalAdd(final String s) {
        Map<Character, HashMap> node = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (node.isEmpty() || !node.containsKey(character)) {
                internalAdd(s.substring(i), node);
                break;
            }
            node = node.get(character);
        }
        node.put(END_CHARACTER, new HashMap<>());
    }

    private void internalAdd(final String s, Map<Character, HashMap> node) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            node.put(character, new HashMap<>());
            node = node.get(character);
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(final String s) {
        Map<Character, HashMap> node = root;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (node.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            Character character = s.charAt(i);
            if (node.containsKey(character)) {
                node = node.get(character);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return node.containsKey(END_CHARACTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree on the first point. But for the second, we have a problem with the 2nd iteration of the loop - root.get(character) will stay at the "top level". That's what we have the "node" element (i.e. the current node).

Comment: Ahhh, I thought (in my mind only) that there is a break out of the loop. Will remove this part.

Answer (score 2):

Use interface types instead of implementations. Instead of:

> ```
> HashMap<Character, HashMap> node = new HashMap<>();
> ```

Do like this:

```
Map<Character, HashMap> node = new HashMap<>();
```

---

Immutable things are good. If you can make member variables `final`, make them `final`:

```
private final Map<Character, HashMap> root = new HashMap<>();
```

After this step, the constructor without arguments becomes completely pointless, so you can remove it.

```
class Trie {
    private final Map<Character, HashMap> root = new HashMap<>();
    private final Character END_CHARACTER = '$';

    public Trie(String s) {
        add(s);
    }

    public Trie(Collection<String> collection) {
        for (String s : collection) {
            add(s);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think the parameterless constructor should be kept so one can also create a instance without a `String/Collection<String>` and later on call one of the `add()` methods

Comment: If there is a real and legitimate use case, then sure, you'll have no choice but add it. Otherwise don't speculate: if you don't need it right now then omit it.